# How to fix Error Cannot Find Module for nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, module.exports

I have a function I've made in a .js file and I'm trying to import and use the function in a get route for an application build but i keep getting this error

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './crawler/ocr-crawler.js'
```

this is how the function is set up:

```
async function OcrCrawlerTest(){

 // some code here
}

module.exports = {OcrCrawlerTest};
```

and this is how I am calling it:

```
const { OcrCrawlerTest } = require('./crawler/ocr-crawler.js');
```

im new to javascript so please give some detail in the solution

also if needed my path structure is set up as shown:

```
--- main directory 
    └── app.js
    └── crawler
         └── ocr-crawler.js
    └── routes
         └── crawler.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "app.js" file, you can use the code below. NodeJS will walk through your directory to find the appropriate module.

```
const { OcrCrawlerTest } = require('./crawler/ocr-crawler'); // remove ".js" at the end
```

You can find more information in this [document](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-at-scale-module-system-commonjs-require/)

---

**EDIT**
In case you're requiring OcrCrawlerTest from `routes/crawler.js` file, you need to provide the relative path from `routes/crawler.js` file to `crawler/ocr-crawler.js` file:

```
const { OcrCrawlerTest } = require('../crawler/ocr-crawler');
```

Comment: after trying this i still had the error but thank you!

Comment: I updated my answer in case you're requiring OcrCrawlerTest from `routes/crawler.js` file

Comment: Thank you so much!! I really appreciate the help and this managed to fix the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `module.exports = {OcrCrawlerTest}` to `module.exports = OcrCrawlerTest;` and `const { OcrCrawlerTest } = require('./crawler/ocr-crawler.js')` to `const OcrCrawlerTest  = require('./crawler/ocr-crawler.js')`

Comment: after trying this i still had the error but thank you for your help!